# Is it overkill to check client sent jwt and paramater are equal?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, authorization

When modifying or deleting a user, is it an overkill to first get the jwt token from the client side, then check to see if the userID parameter matches the jwt id sent from the client, can I assume that if the user has the correct id parameter, then it is indeed the user, and not an malicious user?

Would this be an overkill?

```
if (req.params.userId !== jwtDecoded.user._id) return res.status(401).send('Access denied');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked a good question, and it actually uncovers what might be thought of as a defect in the JWT pattern.  The short answer is, no, if you receive a JWT and the server verifies that it has not been tampered with, then you can safely assume that the bearer is whatever user ID be continued with the claims of that token.

The problem is that there are a number of scenarios in which you still would not want to honor that incoming JWT.  Here is a partial list:

- Someone has managed to steal the JWT of another user, and is now masquerading as that user
- The user does match the JWT, but you have, for whatever reason, decided to block that user from continuing to use your service
- The user matches the JWT, but just a few moments ago the user has logged out, but is still trying to use the same JWT

In all of these examples, your server would be receiving what is a perfectly valid JWT.  However, the server would not want to *honor* that JWT.  There are a number of ways to handle this.  One lean way to handle it would be to maintain a blacklist cache of JWTs which have been logically revoked.  Here is how this blacklist cache might be used to avoid the above scenarios:

- The user whose phone was stolen contacts your site, and informs them of the theft
- Upon discovering a user engaging in malicious behavior on your site, you immediately blacklist their existing JWT
- When a user logs out, you add their JWT to the blacklist

In all cases, now when an incoming JWT hits the server, you perform *two* logical checks.  First, you check the claims of that JWT (e.g. `exp`) to make sure that it has not expired, for example.  Second, you quickly hit the blacklist cache to make sure that the user's JWT is not present there.  If either of these checks fail, you drop the request and send back an error message.

Comment: Thanks!!! The fist bullet point you mentioned, `Someone has managed to steal the JWT of another user, and is now masquerading as that user`, I'm assuming from that, that it isn't a good idea to store the userID in a jwt?

Comment: Not at all...the whole point of a JWT is to maintain user state outside of the application, at little or no storage/performance cost to the application.  As long as you encourage your users to avoid Internet cafes, the only way for someone to get a hold of a user's JWT is by stealing their stuff.